# CSS not serving in NGINX

Tags: php, docker, nginx

i'm trying to run a simple php app using nginx, the file structure looks like this

```
nginx
- nginx.conf
- Dockerfile
php
- css
  -- index.css
- pages
  -- home.php
  -- contact.php
  -- 404.php
- index.php
- images
  --pfp.jpg
- Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

when booting up the server, the pages load perfectly, but i keep getting an error 404 when looking for the css files

here is the nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    # Root directory for the server
    root /var/www/html;

    # Index file configuration
    index index.php;

    # Error pages
    error_page 404 /pages/404.php;

    # PHP handler
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass    php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
    }

    # Serve image files (jpg, jpeg, png, gif) at the root level image directory
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
        root /var/www/html/images;
        expires 30d;
    }

    # Serve CSS files from /css directory
    location /css/ {
        alias /var/www/html/css/;
        expires 30d;
    }
    # General location block to handle other files or directories if needed
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

i've mostly tried changing the nginx configuration file as i think that's the problem but maybe it could be the php routing conflicting with the nginx routing as i have this in index.php

```
<?php
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$viewDir = './pages/';

switch ($request) {
    case '/':
        //import styles
        require './pages/home.php';
        break;
    case '/info':
        echo "Home page requested";
        require './pages/home.php';
        break;
    case '/contact':
        echo "Contact page requeste d";
        require $viewDir . 'contact.php';
        break;
    default:
        echo "404 - Page not found";
        http_response_code(404);
        require $viewDir . '404.php';
        break;
}
?>
```

because when going to /css/index.css i get my 404.php page

Comment: The `alias` and `root` directives you are using within those locations seem superfluous at best, but are possibly causing some issues, too.

Comment: Also, performing an `echo` before `http_response_code` should actually be raising a warning. The latter sends an HTTP header which must happen before any content is written to the body.

Comment: Lastly, it is not necessarily wrong, but using the same 404 page for both your router and for Nginx is asking for trouble while debugging. You should find some way to identify if Nginx is giving the 404, or if it is your router.